# xampp does not work after reboot machine, can't find localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I installed XAMPP on my machine. 
Set up a database in phpmyadmin. Set up a wordpress environment and installed wordpress project. Everything worked perfectly

But after a reboot of the machine, the browser will not find anything at localhost in the browser

-I run on Windows 10.
- During installation, I got a warning that I could not put it in program files(86) because of user controls. So put it in C://xampp
- did not manage to start up apache, so I changed the ports to something random; 8181 and 4434.

In the browser, if I type in localhost:8181 it find xampp dashbord. If I type in localhost:8181/phpmyadmin, it find phpmyadmin settings sites.
But it will not find my wordpress project when I type either localhost/wordpressname or localhost:8181/wordpressname.

I want to access my wordpress project by just typing in localhost/wordpressname in my browser. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: In order for your localhost to be at http://localhost/, your Apache needs to run at port 80.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is without editing your hosts file

Comment: I answered my own question below, thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem.
When changing the ports I went inside apache httpd.conf and changed everything from 80 to 8181. 
Then I went into the httpd.ssl.conf and changed everything from 443 to 4434.

I should not change anything on the 80 port for it to work. After I changed httpd.conf ports back to 80, everything seems to work.
Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the problem is opening DOS as administrator and tipe the following line:

> NET stop HTTP

It will stops all windows services that use the port 80 and you will good to go starting XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

After restart before you start your wordpress on your browser, first go to the XAMPP Control Panel and start Apache and MySQL  and you are good to go since they stop automatically after restart/reboot